# Convergence of a series of a sequence of powers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $\rho\in]0,1[$ and $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of positive integers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\infty$. Consider the following series:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}^\infty \rho^{u_n}$$
Q : What is the condition on the sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the above series converges ?

So far, I can see that it is enough to have $u_n<u_{n+1}$.

But does $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\infty$ suffice ?

Comment: No of course that doesn't suffice. Just take $\rho = 1/2$ and $(u_1,u_2,\dots) = (1,1,\dots,1,1,2,2,\dots,2,2,3,3,\dots,3,3,\dots)$ where you put enough 1's,2's,3's, etc to make it diverge

Comment: According to root test, it depends on $\frac{u_{n+1}-u_n}{n}$.

Comment: For future reference, "series" is both singular and plural.  Thus the question is about the convergence of this particular *series*.  "Serie" does not have any meaning in English.

Comment: Let $c_k=\#\{n:u_n=k\}$ records the number of terms with the value $k$. Then your series is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k\rho^k,$$ and so, we can apply Cauchy-Hadamard theorem to deduce that this converges when $$\rho<R:=\frac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}c_k^{1/k}}$$ and diverges if $\rho>R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_n:=\rho^{u_n}$, which is virtually an arbitrary sequence. You have little other option than studying the convergence of $a_n$, for which there isn't a universal criterion.

For instance, with 
$$a_n=\log_{1/\rho}(n),$$

we have an harmonic series, for which the ratio and root tests are known to fail.